# Is it possible to call an ActiveAdmin member action using a plain ruby form submit button?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The situation: I'm using a very old/specific version of ActiveAdmin(AA 0.5.0, contained within the specific gem activeadmin-mongoid, which is also an old version (0.0.1))

What I want to do: Call the member action I've defined within an activeadmin page for a specific collection member. The reason I'm not using Formtastic is because the version of Formtastic contained within the version doesn't seem to support f.action/actions, or even the older f.buttons. Upgrading any of the versions of the gems used isn't currently an option(unfortunately.)

I'm mostly looking for a yes/no, because I'd rather figure it out myself if it is possible, and look into other options if it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, e.g.

```
= form_for @foo, url: preview_foo_admin_path(@foo) do |f|
```

(Assuming your member action is called `preview`)